# Scraping URLs from Bing image search results

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, bing

I'm building a scraping script in R to fetch product images from search engines. At the current stage I've managed to successfully fetch the URLs that contain images from Google Image Search with the below code snippet:

```
google_urls <- GET("https://www.google.com/search?q=WWF%20CUB%20CLUB%20WWF16215003&tbm=isch", user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36") %>%
                 read_html() %>%
                 html_nodes(xpath = "//td/a") %>% 
                 html_attr("href") %>%
                 `[`(str_detect(., "/url\\?")) %>%
                 strsplit("=|\\&") %>%
                 sapply(`[`, 2)
```

In order to extend the search of the scraping solution, I wish to also scrape similar URLs from Bing. However when I replicate the code below for Bing I'm not getting any results back. In fact, bing_urls is empty when running the code block.

```
bing_urls <- GET("https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=WWF%20CUB%20CLUB%20WWF16215003", user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36") %>%
                read_html() %>%
                html_nodes(xpath = "//td/a") %>% 
                html_attr("href") %>%
                `[`(str_detect(., "/url\\?")) %>%
                strsplit("=|\\&") %>%
                sapply(`[`, 2)
```

How may I amend the bing code block to get similar type of URLs like the initial one for Google?

Comment: hi nba2020! I ran your code, and the first one doesn't actually get the URLs for the images, it gets the URLs for the pages they are from. Is that what you want, or did you want the actual file URLs?

Comment: Thanks @Mark. Indeed I want to get the URLs for the pages they are from. I process them at a later stage in my code flow. I don't want to get the actual file URLs at this stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below returns similar results to the example code you gave for Google Search:

```
library(httr)

GET("https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=WWF%20CUB%20CLUB%20WWF16215003", user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36") %>%
                read_html() %>%
                html_nodes(".lnkw") %>%
                html_nodes("a") %>%
                html_attr("href")
```

It would also be remiss of me not to mention that [Bing has an API](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/apis/bing-web-search-api), and [scraping appears to be against their terms of use](https://about.ads.microsoft.com/en-au/resources/policies/web-crawling), so maybe don't pound their servers, otherwise you're likely to get blocked.